# capture build number of downstream job in Jenkins code as pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there an environment variable that captures the downstream job's build number ?
I am using build step in pipeline as code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an environment variable, but an object property:

```
downstreamBuild = build 'myDownstreamJob'
downstreamBuildNumber = downstreamBuild.rawBuild.id
```

Note that you will either need to disable the Groovy sandbox or get script approvals in order to use `rawBuild`.  Also, you cannot use `wait: false` with your build step, since `build()` returns `null` when called with `wait: false`.

Comment: So how do I captured the build number when wait:false?

Comment: @anandhu you can't, at least not easily.  With `wait: false`, `build()` does not wait for a build to start before returning, there is no build number or other build information available.