# List downstream jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I got jenkins job that starts numerous downstream jobs
Does jenkins job run keeps accessible information on those such as jobName and buildNum ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve downstream job build details in a Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47074189/how-to-retrieve-downstream-job-build-details-in-a-jenkins-pipeline)

Comment: @NoamHelmer no, there is no answer at this topic only WO that doesn't work

Comment: The link from @NoamHelmer is valid. Essentially, Jenkins doesn't have that info in the the upstream job, but the Downstream jobs do record the "Cause" pointing at the upstream job. The given answer is tedious if you have A LOT of jobs and build history on your instance, but it's a valid solution.